# Strange crashes when accessing the memory

Tags: c++, memory, crash

I got this program that worked well 2 weeks ago, I didn't change any parts on where it now crashes.

For example, take this snippet : (assuming `is` is a valid `istream` and contains `<tag>`)

```
std::string Str;
char c;
for ( ; is >> c; )
{
    std::cout << c << std::flush;
    Str += c;
}
```

Output :
`<`
then crash.

I'm using Windows and mingGW, the crash is a window saying that my program has encoutner an error, Windows is trying to fix it...

But this is not all, it crashes the same with `Str = c;` or when initilizing : `std::string Str ("op");`

30 minutes after I have found this error, I got another one (previous to the initial one) on a line :

`osstr.write((char *) Word, 16);`

Where `osstr` is a valid ostringstream and Word is a filled `unsigned char *`

Edit:

The problem is probably NOT in the code. Because a simple call to the string constructor crashes.

`std::string Str ("")` works

`std::string Str ("str");` crash

Comment: Unrelated: instead of the awkward `for` loop, you can simply loop `while(is >> c)`.

Comment: Can you post a complete, self-contained compilable example the exhibits the problem? Because we don't know what any of the things your code references actually are. (The bug is likely in code that runs before this code.)

Comment: [Works fine here](http://ideone.com/uWBv5), your problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @perelo - The error is likely in the part you *did* change. Overwriting memory will have strange effects in other parts of the program. Like this one.

Comment: Run a debug version under Windbg, likely you will see an exception earlier than you do now, currently pointing you to the proximate cause rather than the eventual demise

Comment: its the loop, locks the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, sorry for incomplete information, but I just couldn't give you the whole code.

The problem came from a buffer overflow far before the code above that didn't crash.